# Facebook Api, PHP SDK, Error only for review team

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i'm trying to get my first app approved, i've got about 10 testers and app's works fine for me and for them.
The problem is that when i submit it for approval, reviewer says that he cant log in, and attached i got a blank page showed after login.
here's a simplified version of index.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
set_time_limit(0); 
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome'); 


require_once( 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookPermissionException.php' );
require_once( 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'libraries/Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'libraries/Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
require_once( 'libraries/Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'libraries/Facebook/FacebookServerException.php' );


use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;



$id = 'app_id'; 
$secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$permissions = array(   
'user_videos',
'user_posts',
'public_profile'
);



FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($id, $secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://app_url.com');
try{
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
}catch(Exception $e){

}
if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){
    $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['token']);

    try{

        $session->Validate($id, $secret);
    }catch(FacebookAuthorizationException $e){
        $session = '';

    }
}



if(isset($session)){

        /* do something*/

}

else{ 
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl( $permissions );
    $_SESSION['login'] = $loginUrl;
    include 'php/login.php';

}
```

In the error.log i got this error:

```
[17-Aug-2015 20:09:30 Europe/Rome] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Facebook\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Session has expired, or is not valid for this app.' in /home/user/public_html/my_app/libraries/Facebook/FacebookSession.php:196
Stack trace:
#0 /home/nicosh/public_html/my_app/libraries/Facebook/FacebookSession.php(174): Facebook\FacebookSession::validateSessionInfo(Object(Facebook\GraphSessionInfo), 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...')
#1 /home/nicosh/public_html/my_app/index.php(58): Facebook\FacebookSession->validate('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in /home/user/public_html/my_app/libraries/Facebook/FacebookSession.php on line 196
```

Now, the differences between me/my testers, and fb reviewer are
1-different locations, we are from Italy, and i set `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');` can this cause the error? everytime i got the notification from reviewer team about 01 pm, so it's a different day from USA, can this affect the token creation?
2-me/testers have a role in app's roles.
Any idea or Suggestion?
Thank Nico.

Comment: Have you tested in different browsers/OS ?
I had an issue where the app would work fine on Firefox/IE, but i found that the tester was using Apple computer, and that caused the error.

Comment: Yes one of my tester use imac. can you tell me more about you issue?

Comment: Our issue was that the session containing the userid would get blocked as a "third party cookie" in some browsers. So depending on browser settings you should make sure you do not rely on a session only.
Our workaround was to place the session, and if not possible then read the signed_request data sent by facebook.
If you're using AJAX you must pass the signed_request and read the userid from there.